# What is the market share of iPhone(all versions) vs iPad (all versions)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there any recent market research available about iPhone vs iPad share in the market? I have found lots of comparison charts which are cross-platform (iOS vs Android etc) but not within the iOS and which device type holds what %page of market. I would be thankful if anybody could help me with that.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question, though it will be hard to find reliable data for. I think you need to reword the title though. "Market share" doesn't apply across devices. Market share is what you compare between competing devices/manufacturers in a vertical segment. What you're asking for is sales volume by iPhone vs iPad. You may find better luck with a properly worded request. And I think this can be answered reasonably accurately by looking through past Apple keynote talks from WWDC -- they usually have sales volume numbers in those.

Comment: Not sure if Apple publishes such numbers, but you can look up in they annual reports. Unless you do mean Market share than specify, world wide and/or against which competitive product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some [numbers](http://files.shareholder.com/downloads/AAPL/2463291388x0xS1193125-12-444068/320193/filing.pdf) for the fiscal year ending in September 2012. You can work from to get what you want.

[image]

Since it is in my blood to do stuff like this, I had to play with it so here is my home work.

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks - I wish I could offer you a box of chocolates for the support.

Comment: @Salman You are welcome, and you did express your thankfulness by Voting up my answer. However, for a box of chocolates, I would work like a slave :)